# Adding javascript on a partner website for providing customer chat support and sales tracking without knowing their FTP Credentials?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ftp

We are providing Chat support for the online visitors and tracking their sales (tracking the sales happened through our support only) for our clients, who are having their online stores.

We have to add a javascript code in their store. But the clients are not willing to provide their FTP credentials.

So is there any alternate way to make this work?

Most of the clients are asking for a single click installation at once they register in our website. Is there any way to automate this?

Even if we assume, most of their stores are in,

1. Shopify
2. Bigcommerce
3. Magento
4. Virtue Mart

Is there any way for creating a module in the above mentioned platforms?

Just let me know all of your ideas and suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a good idea for someone to give you their FTP credentials. I suggest you provide them with a JavaScript code(with an App Key) that they can put in their website by them selves.

Do as `Google analytics`, `Facebook` etc do. They give you a script that links to their `statistics` tool.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Even if we are giving them javascript code, how to track their sales? Even we can track the sales through their payment thank you page, how to track their order amount? Without hard coding their code and just using our provided javascript?